# how to show other clients sent Messages on xmpp multiple clients same user

Tags: xmpp, openfire

Example:A,B clients are the same user,A sent messages To C.How to show these messages On B client.If C sent to this user,A，B also can receive messages.So l can show.But When A sent,B do not konw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use message cabining.To share messages across all devices(clients) of same user.More details about it at https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0280.html

Comment: Yeah,that's it.Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can l ask another question?How to sync these clients of unreads?

Comment: You can look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30437866/xmpp-count-of-unread-messages. It may help you.